# How can I find the deepest and most stack-hungry call chains in a program?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, performance, profiling, stack

I have a program written in OCaml that tends to stack-overflow on platforms with small stacks.

Rather than `ulimit`ing the program to find and solve stack overflows one by one, I'd like to get a sorted list of the deepest (and/or most stack-hungry) call chains in a typical execution.

I can record call graphs using perf:

```
perf record -F 99 --call-graph dwarf -- ./a.out input.txt
```

And then get call chains using  the stackcollapse script in [FlameGraph](https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph).

```
perf script > out.perf
FlameGraph/stackcollapse-perf.pl out.perf > out.folded
```

Unfortunately, the call chains obtained in that way are limited to 127 entries.  `perf report` has an option to show more entries: `--max-stack n`.  But `perf script` doesn't seem to have a similar option.

**How can I record a program's execution, and find the deepest call chains?  What about call chains using the most stack space (accounting for frame sizes rather than just frame count)?**

I'm on Linux Mint 18.2, with kernel 4.4.0-112-generic.

Comment: Is `DTrace` available on your platform?

Comment: Apparently there's https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux; I have never used it.

Comment: It would help if you told us what Linux distribution and version you are using.

Comment: Other options might be `SystemTap` or `ktap`

Comment: @fpmurphy1, indeed, any of these would be fine by me.

Comment: I just tried dtrace4linux. `make load` caused my kernel to panic.

Comment: OCaml code may not map to normal stack use in a straightforward way, so it may be worth to look at ways to get stack information from ocaml natively, e.g. like [here](http://kcsrk.info/ocaml/profiling/2015/10/27/profiling-the-stack/).

Comment: @dirkt I wouldn't worry too much about OCaml: perf with `--call-graph dwarf` works just fine. The only issue is the max depth.